# Query parameter to strip value that contains @ and

Tags: javascript

Example URL: https://www.example.com/?test=123&abc=test@gmail.com&xyz=1233
Expected output: https://www.example.com/?test=123&xyz=1233

Basically i am trying to strip the query parameter which containers email ids.

Here is what i have written:

```
    var url = parent.window.location.href.replace('%40', '@').replace('&amp;', '&');
  if (url.includes('@') && url.includes('.')) {
    var returnurl = '';
    var urlParams = new URLSearchParams(url.substring(url.indexOf('?')));
    var keys = urlParams.keys();
    var entries = urlParams.entries();
    for (pair of entries) {
      if (!(pair[1].includes('@') && pair[1].includes('.'))) {
        if (returnurl != '') {
          returnurl = returnurl + '&' + pair[0] + '=' + pair[1];
        } else {
          returnurl = pair[0] + '=' + pair[1];
        }
      } else {
        url = url.replace(pair[0] + '=' + pair[1], '')
      }
    }
  }
url = url.replace('&&','&');
```

Is there any better way to manage this? I am looking to write it in pure javascript, so need to remove ECMASCRIPT6 related code(for loop in above sample).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```js
var url = "https://www.example.com/?test=123&abc=test@gmail.com&xyz=1233"

var path = url.split('?')[0];
var qp = url.split('?')[1];
qp = qp.split('&').filter(function(param) { return param.indexOf('@') === -1} ).join('&');

var result = path+'?'+qp;

console.log(result);
```

Comment: Sorry, can't use this. I am trying to use the code in Google tag manager and it doesn't like "let". 
Here is the error:
"This language feature is only supported for ECMASCRIPT6 mode or better: let declaration."
Could someone please convert this to simple javascript code?

Comment: GTM is still complaining, unfortunately. "This language feature is only supported for ECMASCRIPT6 mode or better: array destructuring."

Comment: try again with the new answer

Comment: Similar error still: "This language feature is only supported for ECMASCRIPT6 mode or better: arrow function."

Comment: @Vinod find the updated code. Having used ES6 for a long time, it is kind of hard to know what is supported/not supported in ES5 runtimes.

Comment: Yep, this seems to be accepted by GTM as well ... :)

Answer (score 2):

You can use the [URL](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/URL) constructor, iterate the [`URLSearchParams`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/URLSearchParams) instance with it's `forEach` method, and delete keys that have the `@` sign in their value, and then convert the URL back to string:

```js
function stripEmail(urlStr) {
  var url = new URL(urlStr);
  
  url.searchParams.forEach(function(value, key) {
    if(value.includes('@')) url.searchParams.delete(key);
  });
  
  return url.toString();
}


var url = 'https://www.example.com/?test=123&abc=test@gmail.com&xyz=1233';

var result = stripEmail(url);

console.log(result);
```